# XTZ Stuck in Failed Transaction

Tags: transactions, error

I used Plenty to exchange XTZ to CTEZ using the AirGap wallet. But for some reason the transaction failed, and I never received CTEZ. Only shows as pending on AirGap, and on the block explorer shows as a failed transaction.

What do I need to do to get my XTZ back?

The transaction hash is : opPfnWztbcjxHtM9wnh7XZ933hfJmwZuUzSgjD2Y3j7dGhrWcQm

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything to get it back, the XTZ wasn't taken.

According to TzKT.io (https://tzkt.io/opPfnWztbcjxHtM9wnh7XZ933hfJmwZuUzSgjD2Y3j7dGhrWcQm) the operation tried to swap more XTZ than was in your wallet. So the operation failed, and no XTZ was taken. Your wallet still has the 10 XTZ in it: https://tzkt.io/tz1ekSS5uaTwve5gjCxLkfUtdDsAqiTi8V2w/operations/

One of the apps involved likely has an issue calculating the max that can be swapped, not taking into account the network fees, and tries to allow users to spend their entire balance, which will always fail

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: @rhw Welcome to Tezos.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. It looks like you've accidentally created multiple accounts; see [this help page for info on how to merge them](/help/merging-accounts).